# How to echo php output? (echoing HTML works)

Tags: php, html, echo

```
      <?php if ( $product['sale'] == "yes") {

            echo'<p>Sale Price: £<?= $product["list_price"];?></p>'; }

                else {echo '<p>Sale Price: £<?= $product["price"];?></p>';}?>
```

The

```
<?= $product["list_price"];?>
```

and

```
<?= $product["price"];?>
```

does not print the values that i have stored in my database, they just don't print anything.

How can I combat this?

Comment: Do you mean `echo'<p>Sale Price: £' . $product["list_price"] . '</p>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP to print PHP in a text quote, you have to use double quotes `"` instead of single `'`. So:

```
<?php if ( $product['sale'] == "yes") {

        echo "<p>Sale Price: £$product['list_price']</p>"; }

            else {echo "<p>Sale Price: £$product['price']</p>";}?>
```

You can even concatenate it like this:

```
echo '<p>Sale Price: £'.$product["list_price"].'</p>';
```

Read the [PHP Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: great! As you can probably see, i'm a beginner and you've really helped me today. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, see the documentation, you have great explanations there, remember to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

by putting **echo** inside an `echo` will result not to display the data from your database. The reason is, you converted it to string. i have another way how to echo it without affecting the `html tag`.

```
<?php 
     if ( $product['sale'] == "yes") {

                      <p>Sale Price: £ <?= $product['list_price']; ?> </p> 

                }else {
                      <p>Sale Price: £ <?= $product['price'];?></p>
                     }

?>
```

Since that the **HTML** statement is inside your **PHP** condition.it will be executed. means... it displaying your desired output.